# Need to print variable in textfield

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables, input

Im working on a WordPress-site where a reservationform is installed.
I want the name of the logged on user is the defaultvalue in the "name" textfield since only loggen on users can make reservations.
The php-code which builds the form looks like this (originial):

```
// Contact details fieldset
'contact'   => array(
'legend'    => __( 'Contact Details', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
'fields'    => array(
        'name'      => array(
        'title'         => __( 'Firmenname', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
        'request_input' => empty( $request->name ) ? '***VALUE***' : $request->name,
        'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
        'required'      => true,
),
```

This continues with other value like Mail and Phonenumber.

I need to get the value from the $user_login - variable printed in the textfield. I tried entering the variable itself, declare it, extending a string and tried to execute php-code. But nothing of this works out.

Is there any other way for printing out the variable in a textfield?

Please dont mind asking futher questions as i cant explain it that detailed.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a user plugin you can just call the current users details and output the user name in the text field

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Contact details fieldset
'contact'   => array(
'legend'    => __( 'Contact Details', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
'fields'    => array(
    'name'      => array(
    'title'         => __( 'Firmenname', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
    'request_input' => $current_user->user_login,
    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
    'required'      => true,
),
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Yes you're right its a plugin.
As i implented your code the page was blank. 
After that I removed the  $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); and it showed up again. 
Why it wont get the user info and runs into some kind of error?

Comment: can you share the rest of the code you are using to build the function

Comment: also try placing the `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` before you start building the form

Comment: http://wp12360441.server-he.de/elma/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/sp-client-document-manager/download.php?fid=OHwyMDE1LTA4LTE0IDEzOjQ0OjQwfGNvZGUudHh0

EDIT: Ignore the Memory 64MB thing, its form an old file i overwrote its NOT in the actual file

Comment: which user plugin are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I use the "restaurant reservations" plugin -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/restaurant-reservations/